# how to change the handles of resizable element dynamically with jquery ui

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a resizable rectangular div with custom handles from the EST and WEST sides like this :

```
$("div.rect").resizable({

    handles: {

            'e': '#egrip'

            'w': '#wgrip'

        }

    // ....
    // ....
})
```

and I have a button which is supposed to change those handles from EST and WEST to **North and South**.

So When I click the button, the 'e,w' handles should disappear and handles from 'n,s' should appear, and the Div will be only resizable from **North and South** directions.

How I can do that ?

Comment: The handles actually use DOM changes, which are only done when the widget is initialised. I don't think they can be changed dynamically, you'd need to call `destroy` then recreate the widget

Comment: @blgt what do you mean by recreate the widget, can you share a snippet of code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the comment:

The handles actually use DOM changes, which are only done when the widget is initialised. I don't think they can be changed dynamically, you'd need to call `destroy` then recreate the widget

So, you'd have to have something like:

```
$("div.rect").resizable({
    handles: {
            'e': '#egrip'
            'w': '#wgrip'
        }
    // ....
    // ....
});
```

Then, when you want to change the resizable handles from `e w` to `n s`:

```
$("div.rect").resizable("destroy");
$("div.rect").resizable({
    handles: {
            'n': '#ngrip'
            's': '#sgrip'
        }
    // ....
    // ....
});
```

Keep in mind that the `destroy` call will also delete the existing handles from the DOM (including, potentially, `#ngrip` and `#sgrip` if they have the resizable handle class). You may need to dynamically save a copy if you want to recycle them later

Here's a fiddle illustrating this https://jsfiddle.net/rmzwodj9/